# How to connect to existing Docker Machine (Now Deprecated) Using Docker Desktop

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, docker-machine

I want to connect (ssh) to an existing docker-machine deployed on AWS EC2. Sadly, the docker-machine feature has now been deprecated (in 2022), and the docs point towards using the Docker Desktop.

I do have Docker Desktop installed on my macbook (m1 chip). But I don't know how I can connect to my docker-machine (on EC2) using it. Is there something I'm missing? Please help.

[image]

Comment: Can you set the `$DOCKER_HOST` environment variable to point there?  (Try running `docker-machine env` to see all of the environment variables it would set.)  Or, can you use a general-purpose system-automation tool (Ansible, Salt Stack, Chef) to manage the remote system?